# Form Validation error on correctly submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am submitting my form correctly but on form validation giving an
error name cannot be empty, but I filled the textbox but the same
error is coming.

```
state = {
degree: "",
data: [],
errors: {},
  };


handleValidations() {
    let data = this.state.data;
    let errors = {};
    let formIsValid = true;

   if (!data["degree"]) {
     formIsValid = false;
     errors["degree"] = "Cannot be empty";
   }

 this.setState({
      errors: errors,
    });
    return formIsValid;
  }
submitHandler = async (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const data = {
      degree: this.state.degree
};
if (this.state.editId === "") {
      if (this.handleValidations()) {
              alert("Form submitted");
      services.postService("education", data).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
}
}
else{
      alert("error");
    }
}
}

  handledegreeChanged = (field, e) => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ degree: data });

    this.setState({
     degree: e.target.value,
    });
  };

 <form>
 <label for="inputdegree" className="col-form-label">
                    Degree
                  </label>
                  <input
                    onChange={this.handleChangeData.bind(this, "degree")}
                    value={this.state.data["degree"]}
                    type="text"
                    ref="degree"
                    className="form-control form-input"
                    id="inputdegree"
                    placeholder="Degree"
                    required
                  />
                  <div style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["degree"]}</div>
 <button
                  onClick={this.submitHandler.bind(this)}
                  type="button"
                  className="submit-button"
                >
</button>
                </form>
```

As in the image below I have entered a field "B.Tech" in the text box but then also it is showing an error message.

Comment: Your code example is incomplete, please provide the complete code example

Comment: The **code formatting** is available in *Visual Studio Code* through the following shortcuts: On Windows `Shift + Alt + F`. On Mac `Shift + Option + F`. On Linux `Ctrl + Shift + I`.

Comment: @konekoya I have provided code for one input as the code is very big

Comment: Try deleting as many codes as possible to narrow down your error

Comment: Please share the code for handleChangeData function. Also, when are you calling handledegreeChanged function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like handledegreeChanged function is supposed to be your onChange function for degree input. If that is the case then modifying the handledegreeChanged function to this will solve your problem:

```
handledegreeChanged = (field, e) => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ data, degree: e.target.value });
};
```